# JSF navigation rule not working on menu

Tags: java, jsf

My commandlink on menu.xhtml did not work. I have my menu.xhtml in template folder under WebContent and list.xhtml in pages folder under WebContent as well. When i click on the link in my menu.xhtml it did not go to list.xhtml page but it did reach the method being called.

menu.xhtml

```
<h:commandLink action="#{UserManagerBean.goListPage}">
                         <h:outputText value="List"/>     
                     </h:commandLink>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
        <display-name>template/menu.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/template/menu.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{UserManagerBean.goListPage}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/list.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Post your code in `menu.xhtml` - the link and the navigation rule from the `faces-config.xml`

Comment: are you sure your method returns `success` ?

Comment: yes, i am sure it returns success

Comment: can you post  goListPage method code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem with

```
 <from-view-id>/template/menu.xhtml</from-view-id>
```

I think you are including this menu in some page as a part of template.

Try just changing

```
 <from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id>
```

but here you must be sure that your `#{UserManagerBean.goListPage}` is not being called by any other pages from `/pages/` or handle accordingly.

Comment: @aFish check update `<from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id> ` It will work

Comment: hai, after i change to <from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id> it works. May i know why? My template located at template folder, it should be <from-view-id>/template/*</from-view-id> but why is <from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id>? Thank you so much

Comment: It is because your menu is used in the actual page not as individual and your actual page is located in `/pages/` go ahead any mark it as answer